# Trying to use array_keys with two levels array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Trying to use array_keys with two levels array but don't know how:

This does not work:

```
<?php
$myarray['a'][]='b';

$an_id='b';

$eval="a";
$check=array_keys($myarray,$an_id);

if(in_array($eval,$check)){
echo 'found';
}
?>
```

Two levels array.

But this does:

```
<?php
$myarray['a']='b';

$an_id='b';

$eval="a";
$check=array_keys($myarray,$an_id);

if(in_array($eval,$check)){
echo 'found';
}
?>
```

Single level array.

Comment: Couldn't this be simplified to `$myarray[$eval] === $an_id`?

Comment: No as $myarray[$eval][] is precisely an array with multiple values, therefore the use of array_keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example does not work because you search `b` string while `$myarray['a']` contains an array with a `b` string, so just replace your following line:

```
$an_id='b';
```

for this one:

```
$an_id= array('b');
```

so you search for the correct value inside `$myarray`, with that change your first example will work.

See working [**example**](http://codepad.org/IAK2TKdm)